# / Usr / bin / ld: cannot found -lboost_thread-mt

Tags: c++, mongodb

I am trying to install the library mongodb for C ++  and follow to the letter the instruction but when i run the program using the liena of code:

```
g++ tutorial.cpp -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -o tutorial
```

i get the following error:

```
/ Usr / bin / ld: cannot  found -lboost_thread-mt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What can i do to fix this error?

Comment: Your other Boost libraries are without the `-mt` suffix, which one is correct? By the way, the `-mt` suffix is related to how Boost was built, either *all* libraries should have the suffix, or none.

Comment: You need to build or install Boost differently.  A single-threaded version probably doesn't have the thread library.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg if i take thje -mt off y get this error: (.text + 0x2c3): reference to `ERR_remove_state 'undefined
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status